# Animation in PowerPoint: OS X/Windows compatibility

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

I only have PowerPoint 15 on OS X available to work with.  I need to prepare a presentation which will include animations/videos and will likely be played back on a Windows computer.  I have next to no information about the system where the presentation will run.  I am worried about compatibility: it would be a disaster if the animations don't run.

What is a safe method of including animations (simple videos) that maximizes compatibility?

When I don't know the target system I normally just use PDF, but that's not an option this time as it doesn't support embedded videos in a compatible way.

Comment: With MS Word my experience was that there's isn't 100% format compatibility between the Mac and Windows versions, so I am worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations shouldn't be a problem going from Mac to Windows PPT, so long as the Windows version is same or higher than the Mac version of PPT. When it comes to animation, the Windows version is more capable (generally, it can create effects that the Mac version can only play back).

Fonts would be my biggest worry. If you use one that's not available on the Windows system, another font will be substituted. That may be almost undetectable or may totally throw your formatting/linebreaks off.  Stick with the fonts provided with Office. A couple of links to help with that:

http://presentitude.com/fonts/ 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cross-Platform-PowerPoint-Compatibility-0eebb4f1-c329-4c50-b83c-3af1bab640de

Videos. Always a problem, these things.  If it were my project, I'd insert them on the Mac, find a computer with Windows + PPT 2010 or higher, install QuickTime if the movies don't play right off, then us PowerPoint's File | Info | Optimize Compatibility feature to convert the media files into a format that's as universally Windows-compatible as possible. (Note: you won't see this feature until at least one media file's been inserted).

Comment: I don't mean animations as in moving elements on the slides. I mean videos.  I should not have used the word "animations" at all, but I didn't realize that it will lead to this misunderstanding. I used it because all the videos are simple, low-framerate visualizations.  Many of them would even be suitable for an animated GIF.  There are no videos recorded with a camera.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on fonts (Calibri or any sans-serif will do just fine) and the Optimize Compatibility feature.

Comment: Calibri will be there on any recent PPT installation (as in, anything since 2007). A good choice for this project.